# Simulate Values under custom density

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, kernel-density

I have a theoretical and coding question that has to do with densities and simulating values.

I am building custom densities via the density(x) command. However I am hoping to generate 1000-10000 simulated values from this density. The overall goal is to take two densities build by density(x$y) form and run simulations and say this density A is more than density B x% of the time. I would just take each simulated value and see which is higher and code to count how many times A is higher than B.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or is there some way to accomplish something similar with these densities? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the problem with that is that I am building out a smooth density based on only 86 samples, but I have reason to believe that it can fall anywhere inside the density, so I am hoping to simulate within that density, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sample` function can take the midpoints of the intervals of the sample density and then use the densities as the prob-arguments.

```
mysamp <- sample(x= dens$x, size=1000  , prob=dens$y, repl=TRUE)
```

This has the disadvantage that you may need to jitter the result to avoid lots of duplicates.

```
 mysamp <- jitter(mysamp)
```

Another method is to use `approxfun` and `ecdf`. You may need to invert the function (reverse role of x and y) in order to sample using the input of `runif(1000)` into the result. I'm pretty sure there are worked examples of this in SO and I'm pretty sure that I am one of many who in the past have posted such code to R-help. (If your searches have failed to find then then post the search strategies and others can try to improve upon them.)

Comment: to avoid a warning, use `prob=dens$y/sum(dens$y)`

Answer (score 1):

Following @DWin's tip to invert the `ecdf`, here is how to implement such an approach, using a spline to fit the inverted step-function:

Given

```
z <- c(rnorm(40), runif(40))
plot(density(z))
```

[image]

Define

```
spl <- with(environment(ecdf(z)), splinefun(y, x))

sampler <- function(n)spl(runif(n))
```

Now you can call `sampler()` with the size you want:

```
plot(density(sampler(1000)))
```

[image]

Final note: This will never generate values outside the range of the original data, but duplicates will be extremely rare:

```
> anyDuplicated(sampler(1e4))
[1] 0
```